# SKPhysicsBody slowing down game

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

I have tons of the same node in game all generated randomly, and when I run the project by itself, it runs very smoothly. However, when I use this physics body (or any) it slows down tremendously:

```
circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 25)
```

How do I fix this? Will post more code if necessary.

Edit:

```
    func createCirclesOnLine(line: CGFloat) {
    var currentY : CGFloat = -110000
    let maxY = self.size.width * 15
    let spacing : CGFloat = 120
    while currentY < maxY {
        let circle = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "first@2x")

                   circle.position = CGPointMake(line,  currentY)
      circle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: circle.size)
        circle.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
        circle.physicsBody?.restitution = 1

        circle.size = CGSizeMake(75, 75)
        let up = SKAction.moveByX(0, y: 9000, duration: 90)
        circle.runAction(up)
        foregroundNode.addChild(circle)
        currentY += CGFloat((random() % 400) + 70)
    }
```

Comment: how many physics bodies do you have

Comment: Well, one for each node but called once. I have thousands of nodes.

Comment: theres a limit to how many collisions you can process before the game slows down

Comment: Well shit. Is there anything else I can do to get physics bodies without slowing it down?

Comment: you can use physics, but thousands of physics bodies is probably too much to expect a good frame rate.  use less

Comment: Ok, but I need collision detection. Is there a way to get that without `circleOfRadius`?

Comment: using a physics body in the shape of a rectangle might be less expensive, but then your circles will collide like rectangles instead of circles.  might look weird.

Comment: I will try this.  I don't see why it wouldn't work.

Comment: because you have too many sprites on the screen at once.  it needs to process all those collisions on each frame.

Comment: that won't add much efficency,  the issue here is not the physics body,  but how it is being used

Comment: Okay @Knight0fDragon, do you have another suggestion?

Comment: don't know how you are using them,  do all 1000 bodies need to bounce off each other

Comment: I have one player that moves up and down a line with all these circles and jumps to another line. ( the goal is to avoid the circles) I can't call my GameOver SKScene without collision detection.

Comment: you are going to have to paste more code,  it seems like the only things that need to collide is 1 player and 1000 balls

Comment: It looks like you are creating physics bodies for all of the circles.  Even the ones that aren't on the screen.  Why not wait until they are on the screen before giving them a body and then removing it once they are off the screen?

Comment: where is the category setup,  remember be default items are set to be able to hit EVERYTHING

Comment: Woah @TrentSartain, good idea. How can I do this?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon they're called in GameScene many, many times.

Comment: @TrentSartain  that is actually a bad idea,  that is something that should be done on the loading phase,

Comment: @Knight0fDragon I've never had it be an issue for me.  I just set up collision points on entry and exits and change them accordingly.

Comment: @TrentSartain can you give me an example?

Comment: when it comes to 1 or 2 objects, and not a lot going on,  sure you may not notice a lag

Comment: @Rae Tucker by default, zero out all your bitmasks

Comment: So to @Knight0fDragon's point, perhaps instead of dynamically creating and removing physics bodies, you can create significantly fewer circles and when the circle moves above the screen, you just recycle it and put it back down to the bottom of the line.  Then you can just move it up again.

Comment: @TrentSartain I don't know how to do that haha

Comment: Do you plan on having 1000 circles on screen at once?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon no. I have a scrolling background.

Comment: Can somebody start a chat so we arent spamming the comments... I tried but I got an error

Comment: How many do you plan on having at once

Comment: @Knight0fDragon 40-50 at most

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98843/discussion-between-knight0fdragon-and-rae-tucker).